# How do I add a pay later option with a Stripe payments integration?

Tags: stripe-payments

I have an order form that uses a Stripe payment integration and I also want to add a checkbox for a option to "Pay Later" which will be an invoice directly to their company and in turn it will cancel the need for the Stripe payment. The problem i'm having is the Stripe library passes validation for card info and it stops the form submit if anything is empty or invalid in the Stripe integration.

Answer (score 0):

Stripe has [a guide for setting up future payments](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-and-reuse) which covers a lot of scenarios.  The basic, high-level steps are:

1. Create a Setup Intent
2. Collect payment information
3. Use the Setup Intent to set the payment information up for later use and attach it to a Customer object in Stripe

Once that's done you can then charge/invoice the Customer later.

Comment: What if I handle customer invoices in quickbooks, and they won't be handled from Stripe later?

Comment: You can mark an Invoice in Stripe as `paid_out_of_band`: https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoices/pay#pay_invoice-paid_out_of_band